# WildFly exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: NonTxInvocationContext cannot be cast to TxInvocationContext

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly-8

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.infinispan.context.impl.NonTxInvocationContext cannot be cast to org.infinispan.context.impl.TxInvocationContext
```

I got this exception in wildfly-8.2 domain with JPA - hibernate L2C enabled. Please help if anyone know the solution.

Comment: Are you including an Infinispan dependency in your deployment?

Comment: In the ear file, there is only hibernate settings to enable L2C and cacheable annotation. Infinispan used is built in wildfly hull-ha configuration.

Comment: It looks like there is two versions of Infinispan being found. Make sure you don't have an Infinispan library in your EAR or any WAR's.